# Add result source refinement in SharePoint 2013 search

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-search

how can i filter between result sources in SharePoint 2013 search. 
can i add a refinement tab that allows me to further filter the search depending upon all the result sources available.
I have added 5 result sources 
source 1,2,3,4,5
in the search page first i get search from all the result sources..
Then i filter down with the result source..is there a way we can do it in 2013.

there was a way to do this in 2010 we can add a xml to the refinement table which is not present now

I have this category in 2010 which came from the out of the box refinement panel i am trying to add this category to 2013 Search refinement panel

how can i add this in the refinement panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the link that shows how to do it 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30147.refine-sharepoint-2013-search-with-content-sources.aspx